# Unable to delete empty project folders in Informatica Application Integration

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I have two empty project folders in Application Integration that I want to delete.
[image]

However, when attempting to delete them I receive an error:
[image]

The projects do not contain anything. No folders, no assets. They have all been deleted.
[image]

Why I am getting this error? How do I delete the projects?

Comment: May be stop Informatica process, delete them and then restart? That process may be using or referencing to these folders. I know they are empty but sometime programs still can refer to some folders.

Answer (score 2):

Informatica cloud some times have browser cache issues. Log in from chrome incognito mode and try to delete them.